# how to make a getter that list of persons whose birthday is in this week in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple class named Person, having three fields name, country and birthdate.

here I want to make a getter that returns a list of persons whose birthday is coming to this week.

and one more thing that I am getting error:

```
Person class contains a field named birthday which type is DateTime
```

How to assign value to `DateTime`?. I am doing as following which showing an error with birthday field

```
Person(name: 'Alex',country: 'Zambia',birthdate: '12-09-1990'),
```

```
class Person
{
  String name;
  String country;
  DateTime birthdate;
  
  Person({required this.name,required this.country,required this.birthdate});
  
}
```

and here is the code where I will use this getter for displaying user list

```
class myscreen extends StatelessWidget {
   myscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  List<Person> personlist=[
    Person(name: 'Alex',country: 'Zambia',birthdate: '12-09-1990'),
    Person(name: 'Suzi',country: 'Laos',birthdate: '14-08-1980'),
    Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: '27-09-2002'),
  ];

  List<Person> get person_birthday_thisweek{
    List<Person> templist=[];

    //what to code to get the list of persons whose birthday is in this week

    return templist;
  }
```

Comment: in your model you define birthdate as DateTime but in variable you pass string to it?

Comment: Yes...this is what I don't know how to apply value here

Comment: like name:'xyz' so how to value birthdate:??   (here I want to give value 12-09-1990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first issue you can convert your string to DateTime by using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package, like this:

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
        .parse('12-09-1990');
```

but let assume your list is like this:

```
List<Person> personlist = [
    Person(name: 'Alex', country: 'Zambia', birthdate: DateTime(1990, 09, 12)),
    Person(name: 'Suzi', country: 'Laos', birthdate: DateTime(1980, 08, 14)),
    Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateTime(2002, 09, 27)),
    Person(name: 'Lysadli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateTime(2022, 10, 03))
  ];
```

so change your get method to this:

```
List<Person> get person_birthday_thisweek {
    final date = DateTime.now();
    DateTime startDate =
        getDate(date.subtract(Duration(days: date.weekday - 1)));
    DateTime endDate =
        getDate(date.add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - date.weekday)));

  List<Person> templist = personlist
    .where((element) =>
        (startDate.isBefore(element.birthdate) ||
            startDate == element.birthdate) &&
        endDate.isAfter(element.birthdate))
    .toList();

  return templist;
}
```

the result would be:

```
for (var element in person_birthday_thisweek) {
  print("object = ${element.birthdate}");
}
//2022-10-03 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.. and use this package for DateTime format [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install)

```
List<Person> personlist = [
Person(name: 'Alex', country: 'Zambia', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('12-09-1990')),
Person(name: 'Suzi', country: 'Laos', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('04-10-2022')),
Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('01-10-2022')),
Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('09-10-2022')),
Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('28-10-2022')),
Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('29-10-2022')),
Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('10-10-2022')),
Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse('11-10-2022')),
];
    List<Person> birthdayWeekList = [];
    for (var element in personlist) {
    if (element.birthdate.year == DateTime.now().year) {
  if (element.birthdate.month == DateTime.now().month) {
    DateTime lastDateOfWeek = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7 - DateTime.now().weekday));
    if (lastDateOfWeek.difference(element.birthdate).inDays <= 7 && lastDateOfWeek.difference(element.birthdate).inDays >= 0) {
      if (DateTime.now().weekday <= element.birthdate.weekday) {
        birthdayWeekList.add(element);
      }
    }
   }
 }
}
  for (var e in birthdayWeekList) {
    print('tempDate===>${e.birthdate}');
   }
```

[image: results is here]

Answer (score 0):

i update it for month end date
in dart you can parse string to datetime DateTime.parse('1900-10-08 00:00:00.000')

```
List<Person> get person_birthday_thisweek{
List<Person> personlist = [
    Person(name: 'PPP',country: 'Zambia',birthdate: DateTime.parse('1900-10-08 00:00:00.000')),
    Person(name: 'LLL',country: 'Zambia',birthdate: DateTime.parse('1900-09-29 00:00:00.000')),
    Person(name: 'Alex',country: 'Zambia',birthdate: DateTime.parse('1990-10-03 00:00:00.000')),
    Person(name: 'Suzi',country: 'Laos',birthdate: DateTime.parse('1980-08-14 00:00:00.000')),
    Person(name: 'Lyli', country: 'Nepal', birthdate: DateTime.parse('2002-09-27 00:00:00.000')),
  ];
  List<Person> templist=[];
  var now = DateTime.now();
  //now = DateTime.parse("2022-10-01 13:13:40.305728");
  print(now);
  var start = now.day - now.weekday;
  var lst = List.generate(7, (index) => DateTime(now.year, now.month, start + index));
  for (var p in personlist) {
    var fakeDate = DateTime(now.year, p.birthdate.month, p.birthdate.day);
    if (lst.contains(fakeDate)) {
      print(p.name);
      templist.add(p);
    }
  }
  return templist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to dart so I'm just going to post this despite other good answers already. I interpreted the problem as "Whose birthday is in the next 7 days?". Here is my solution:

```
for (Person p in personlist) {
  DateTime thisYear = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, p.birthdate.month, p.birthdate.day);
  if (thisYear.isAfter(DateTime.now()) && thisYear.isBefore(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7)))) {
    print("It's ${p.name}'s birthday next week!");
  }
}
```

As others have stated, to parse this format of date you'd need an external package from pub (`intl`). I couldn't bother so I used this parser instead:

```
DateTime parseCustomDate(String date) {
// Parses DateTime from 'dd-mm-YYYY' formatted String
  List<String> comp = date.split('-');
  return DateTime(int.parse(comp[2]), int.parse(comp[1]), int.parse(comp[0]));
}
```

Cheers